# TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined--multer

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, error-handling, multer

I am currently facing a similar problem to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59526207/how-do-i-produce-multer-error-message-in-my-postman). I managed to resolve my initial issue after referencing solutions posted there. However, when i tried to post a image that is less than 1MB and is a jpg formatted image( which i managed to do before the editing), it now fails and state that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined`.

My app.js code:

```
const upload = multer({
    dest: storage,
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
      fileSize: 1024 * 1024
    },
    fileFilter: function(req, file, callback,error) {
        var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        var error_msg = error instanceof multer.MulterError;
        if(ext !== '.jpg') {
             req.fileValidationError = "Not a jpg file!";
             return callback(null, false, req.fileValidationError);
        }
        if(error_msg) {
            req.fileSizeError = "Image more than"
            return callback(null, false, req.fileSizeError)
        }
        callback(null,true)
    }
  });

app.post("/upload", function (req, res, next) {
    upload.single('name')(req, res, function (error) {
        if(req.fileValidationError) {
            res.status(500).send({message:req.fileValidationError});
        }
        else {
            if(error.code === 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE') {
                req.fileSizeError = "Image more than 1MB!";
                res.status(500).send({message:req.fileSizeError});
            }
            else {
                console.log('File Received!');
                console.log(req.file);
                var sql = "INSERT INTO `file`(name,description,type,size) VALUES('" + req.file.filename + "', '" + (req.file.encoding + "_" + req.file.destination + "_" + req.file.path)+ "', '" + req.file.mimetype + "', '" + req.file.size + "')";
                db.query(sql, (error, results) => {
                    console.log('Inserted Data!');
                });
            const message = "Successfully Uploaded!"
            res.status(200).send({message:message, file_details:req.file})
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the error handling isn't right, during file saving in particular; in which the resulting errors are not being handled. For example, try deleting the destination directory "uploads" and then upload a file, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined` will be thrown again!

To resolve this and to determine what exactly is the error, you should handle the `upload.single()` error callback.

```
app.post("/upload", function (req, res, next) {
  upload.single('name')(req, res, function (error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(`upload.single error: ${error}`);
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    }
    // code
  })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The array does only contain objects, not the filename property. The first object in the array does have the filename property. Select the first and only item in it using `req.files['image'][0].filename` or `req.files[0].filename` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your sending in your request header `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 1):

Bingo!! resolved this
For me I was just sending the image name and not the object (const file = event.target.files[0]; file in this case).

Hope this help you:)

Answer (score 0):

Add this `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag its like:

```
<form action="/admin/banner/update?id={{bannerEdit._id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```